# How to get the user ID in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Wordpress installed in my website and I want to upload a single .php file that has to retrieve the user ID which is now logged.

This is my code of the id.php file (in the root of the website), which works:

```
<?php 
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );

$user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 

echo $user_ID;

?>
```

But I am afraid to load wp-load.php in this way. Can it cause problems in the normal work of the blog?

How can I improve my script?

Comment: Why do you want to use a separate file to get an user ID? Provide more details, maybe there is a better way to achieve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about loading wp-load.php, instead load wp-includes/wp-user.php and use the function (shown below) defined on the [WordPress developer site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/).

```
function get_current_user_id() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_get_current_user' ) ) {
        return 0;
    }
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    return ( isset( $user->ID ) ? (int) $user->ID : 0 );
}
```

courtesy of [WordPress](https://www.wordpress.org)